# Compact manifold with positive sectional curvature has a positive lower bound.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

If $(M,g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, with sectional curvature $K$ always positive, how to show there exists a $c>0$, such that $$K\geq c$$
What if for the case $M$ is a homogeneous manifold ?

Comment: The key is that if $M$ is compact, then the Grassmannian bundle of $2$planes on $M$, say $Gr_2(M)$, is also compact, hence the function $K : Gr_2(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on a compact and achieves its lower bound.

Comment: Wonderful！what a Really nice thought ！

Comment: For homogeneous manifolds, it is the same idea: the function $K$ is "independant" of the point $p$, hence you just have to look for $K_p : Gr_2(M)_p \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Didier Thanks, I guess I learned a lot from your thoughts ！

Comment: @Didier: Your argument is true for compact manifolds with boundary?

Comment: @C.F.G Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @Didier: I am not sure but I think one can construct compact manifolds with boundary of $K>0$ but not $K>c$. I am not sure whether this is about compact manifolds with boundary or non-compact manifolds.

Comment: @C.F.G You are talking about complete non-compact counter-example (like the hyperbolic paraboloid): they have $K>0$ but $K\to 0$ at infinity. This is precisely because they are non-compact that we can talk about "infinity"! For compact manifold with or without boundary, there is no big deal to apply the Grasmannian technique.

Comment: @Didier: Is it obvious fact that compactness of $M$ implies compactness of $Gr_2(M)$?

Comment: @C.F.G Not "obvious", but not hard. If $M$ has no boundary, then $Gr_2(M)$ is a fiber bundle with compact fibers and compact base. If it has a boundary, $Gr_2(M)$ is a closed subset of $Gr_2(\overline M)$, where $\overline M$ is the double of $M$, which is compact.